# Divide values across columns using a vector when they are above the value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df like this:

```
  data <- data.frame(
  threshold = c(87.737, 43.5998, 77.9059, 40.8264),
  Ab1 = c(3253.599707, 1633.279433, 947.2430872, 656.468399),
  Ab2 = c(3428.123145, 945.5828298, 77.9059, 40.8264),
  Ab3 = c(4871.762074, 1779.414962, 77.9059, 976.6968863),
  Ab4 = c(2820.643672, 606.0326318, 796.7766849, 824.4061446)
)
```

and a vector like this:

```
vector <- c(2,3,4,5)
```

my goal is:

```
  goal <- data.frame(
  Ab1 = c(1626.799854, 816.6397167, 473.6215436, 328.2341995),
  Ab2 = c(1142.707715, 315.1942766, 77.9059, 40.8264),
  Ab3 = c(1217.940518, 444.8537404, 77.9059, 244.1742216),
  Ab4 = c(564.1287344, 121.2065264, 159.355337, 164.8812289)
)
```

I am trying to divide the values in column Ab1 by 2, Ab2 by 3, Ab3 by 4 and Ab4 by 5 when the value is above the value indicated in "threshold" column.

So 77.9059, 40.8264 were not divided.

So far I have:

```
goal <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Ab"),
                ~ifelse(. > threshold, ./vector, .))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-"threshold")
```

where the first value in the vector is used to divide all values that are above the threshold.

How can I make it so that the entire row is divided by the vector where both have the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.

- extract the divisors from the column names;
- divide each column by the value gotten above (plus 1) conditional on `threshold` in a `mapply` loop.

```r
data <- data.frame(
  threshold = c(87.737, 43.5998, 77.9059, 40.8264),
  Ab1 = c(3253.599707, 1633.279433, 947.2430872, 656.468399),
  Ab2 = c(3428.123145, 945.5828298, 77.9059, 40.8264),
  Ab3 = c(4871.762074, 1779.414962, 77.9059, 976.6968863),
  Ab4 = c(2820.643672, 606.0326318, 796.7766849, 824.4061446)
)
goal <- data.frame(
  Ab1 = c(1626.799854, 816.6397167, 473.6215436, 328.2341995),
  Ab2 = c(1142.707715, 315.1942766, 77.9059, 40.8264),
  Ab3 = c(1217.940518, 444.8537404, 77.9059, 244.1742216),
  Ab4 = c(564.1287344, 121.2065264, 159.355337, 164.8812289)
)

goal2 <- data[-1]
div <- goal2 |> names() |> sub("\\D+", "", x = _) |> as.integer()
goal2[] <- mapply(\(x, d, th) ifelse(x > th, x/(d + 1L), x), goal2, div,
                 MoreArgs = list(th = data$threshold))

all.equal(goal, goal2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `col` like below

```
data[-1] <- data[-1] / vector[col(data[-1])]
```

such that `data` is updated (except for the column `threshold`) as below

```
> data
  threshold       Ab1        Ab2        Ab3      Ab4
1   87.7370 1626.7999 1142.70772 1217.94052 564.1287
2   43.5998  816.6397  315.19428  444.85374 121.2065
3   77.9059  473.6215   25.96863   19.47648 159.3553
4   40.8264  328.2342   13.60880  244.17422 164.8812
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        data <- data.frame(
  threshold = c(87.737, 43.5998, 77.9059, 40.8264),
  Ab1 = c(3253.599707, 1633.279433, 947.2430872, 656.468399),
  Ab2 = c(3428.123145, 945.5828298, 77.9059, 40.8264),
  Ab3 = c(4871.762074, 1779.414962, 77.9059, 976.6968863),
  Ab4 = c(2820.643672, 606.0326318, 796.7766849, 824.4061446)
)

vector <- c(2, 3, 4, 5)

# Apply the division based on the threshold and corresponding vector value
goal <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Ab"), ~ifelse(. > threshold, . / vector[cur_group_id()], .))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-threshold)

goal
```

- cur_group_id() is used to get the current row index within rowwise().
  This index is then used to access the corresponding element in vector
  for division.
- ifelse() checks if the value in each "Ab" column is greater than the
  threshold. If it is, the value is divided by the corresponding
  element in vector; otherwise, it remains unchanged.
- The threshold column is removed at the end using select(-threshold).
  This should give you the desired output where each "Ab" column value
  is divided by the respective value in vector if it exceeds the
  threshold.

Comment: thank you for the answer! It currently divides vertically. Trying out different things now but I'm still stuck.